# How to stop my context processors breaking other apps unit tests?

Tags: django, testing

I have a django project which consists of several projects, as well as `django.contrib.auth`.  When I run `python manage.py test` and the `auth` unit tests are run, django appears to be trying to evaluate all my context processors, including those relating to other apps.

One of my context processors for another app uses `reverse` to look up a URL for a link, and that is failing when inside the `auth` unit tests, causing those tests to fail.  How can I resolve this so that my context processors do not interfere with running unit tests for unrelated apps?

Thanks.

Example test failure (my other app is called 'monitor', and in monitor/context_processors.py, tries to get URL for monitor.views.dashboard)

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test_unknown_user (django.contrib.auth.tests.remote_user.RemoteUserTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/tests/remote_user.py", line 50, in test_unknown_user
    response = self.client.get('/remote_user/', REMOTE_USER='newuser')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 445, in get
    response = super(Client, self).get(path, data=data, **extra)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 229, in get
    return self.request(**r)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 111, in get_response
    response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 79, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/tests/urls.py", line 13, in remote_user_auth_view
    c = RequestContext(request, {})
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/context.py", line 177, in __init__
    self.update(processor(request))
  File "/home/me/hydra/hydra-server/monitor/context_processors.py", line 13, in menu_items
    items.append({"url": reverse('monitor.views.dashboard'), "caption": "Dashboard"})
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 391, in reverse
    *args, **kwargs)))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 337, in reverse
    "arguments '%s' not found." % (lookup_view_s, args, kwargs))
NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'monitor.views.dashboard' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You can fall silently on `NoReverseMatch` (may be with logging the error).
2. You can pass string to reverse in template and then reverse it there with `{% url %}` tag, not in context processor.
3. You can just ignore that, what's the need to test Django if you are not patching it?